# Using the chown linux command to allow permission on a user and group

Tags: linux, chown

The question
Recursively set the owner and group of /home/shared/salesproject/ and its contents to sam and sales.

I know it would start out 'chown -R'

how would the rest go?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to put `sudo` in front of these commands:

```
chown -R sam /home/shared/salesprojects
chgrp -R sales /home/shared/salesprojects
```

You can get documentation on commands using e.g. `man chown` or (for many commands) `chown --help`.